# 404 status code when calling the LinkedIn API

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, http-status-code-404, linkedin-api

I've used the same method for years in order to access LinkedIn's api but about 5 or 7 months ago it stopped working throwing unauthorized errors.

I spent roughly 20 hours on this over two das and I cannot get this to work correctly. I am to the point that I am receive a 404 so at least I know I am making it to the server, I just cannot find my app.

I am in serious need to have this running in less that 8 hours, because I've got a presentation to give spanning three countries and three different teams.

Can someone offer me subsections? I've even post the entire project," about 4 files" below as a link to download the project.

Thanks for any immediate assistance.

Here is the returned headers in case it might help.

```html
These are my urls
   public const string REQUEST_TOKEN = "https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/requestToken?scope=r_emailaddress r_fullprofile rw_groups r_contactinfo r_network w_messages";
    public const string AUTHORIZE = "https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorize";
    public const string ACCESS_TOKEN = "https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken";
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


Called Fuction for Error
webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


Returned from LinkedIn

The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Headers

{P3P: CP="CAO CUR ADM DEV PSA PSD OUR"
Set-Cookie: _lipt=deleteMe; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:10 GMT; Path=/,bcookie="v=2&fad08702-f5c2-469f-8600-39059ab4b21f"; Version=1; Domain=linkedin.com; Max-Age=63072000; Expires=Wed, 21-Feb-2018 05:24:45 GMT; Path=/,leo_auth_token="GST:96L71p-kiEw1K4M5fHA71ND8bdy5mFXFLET7OWVZNNDPKFMhWZNjha:1456118685:2711fd69f192df53a32674f3516ead71d7d4cfb1"; Version=1; Max-Age=1799; Expires=Mon, 22-Feb-2016 05:54:44 GMT; Path=/,sl="delete me"; Version=1; Max-Age=0; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:10 GMT; Path=/,sl="delete me"; Version=1; Domain=.api.linkedin.com; Max-Age=0; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:10 GMT; Path=/,s_leo_auth_token="delete me"; Version=1; Max-Age=0; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:10 GMT; Path=/,visit="v=1&G"; Version=1; Max-Age=63072000; Expires=Wed, 21-Feb-2018 05:24:45 GMT; Path=/,lidc="b=TB14:g=337:u=1:i=1456118685:t=1456205085:s=AQEN7A2vJ0_i7UVbsjezacAngsY4PhXW"; Expires=Tue, 23 Feb 2016 05:24:45 GMT; domain=.linkedin.com; Path=/
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Date: Mon, 22 Feb 2016 05:24:44 GMT
X-FS-UUID: f601d6be3a2c35148007d15f1d2b0000
X-Li-Fabric: prod-ltx1
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
X-Li-Pop: prod-ltx1
X-LI-UUID: 9gHWvjosNRSAB9FfHSsAAA==

}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Stack

   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at oAuthLinkedIn.WebResponseGet(HttpWebRequest webRequest) in D:\Users\Erik Little\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\AlumCloud_Working\AlumCloudOAuth\oAuthLinkedIn.cs:line 331
   at oAuthLinkedIn.WebRequest(Method method, String url, String postData) in D:\Users\Erik Little\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\AlumCloud_Working\AlumCloudOAuth\oAuthLinkedIn.cs:line 308
   at oAuthLinkedIn.oAuthWebRequest(Method method, String url, String postData) in D:\Users\Erik Little\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\AlumCloud_Working\AlumCloudOAuth\oAuthLinkedIn.cs:line 197
   at oAuthLinkedIn.AuthorizationLinkGet() in D:\Users\Erik Little\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\AlumCloud_Working\AlumCloudOAuth\oAuthLinkedIn.cs:line 88
   at AlumCloud.Controllers.EnterpriseController.LinkedIN() in D:\Users\Erik Little\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\AlumCloud_Working\AlumCloud\Controllers\EnterpriseManager\EnterpriseController.cs:line 253
   at AlumCloud.Controllers.EnterpriseController.Social(FormCollection form) in D:\Users\Erik Little\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\AlumCloud_Working\AlumCloud\Controllers\EnterpriseManager\EnterpriseController.cs:line 152
   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.ActionInvocation.InvokeSynchronousActionMethod()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End[TResult](IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
​
```

[Link to linkedIN App](http://f.AlumCloud.Com/help/AlumCloudOAuth.zip)

I also just notice that when returned with a 404 error that it shows in my webResponse tht I've got live connection to LinkedIn. This has to be something very small I'm missing

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCAVp.png)

Comment: Maybe they moved the path to your app, I don't know but if you have a 404 it means the URL you provide is not the good one... Ask them for the correct path if they have a developper support center...

Comment: Thank you so much for you answer. I'm able to successfully authicicate however, NOW IM gtting a wrong callback uril. Believe me I've tried everything under the sun. Please, any suggestions?